# Failed to upload a object to S3 using signed URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have generated signed url using latest aws cli tool. But when i put a object using curl i got `signature does not match error`.

curl command i used
`curl -v -H "content-type:application/vnd.ms-excel" -T users.csv  "https://a054.s3.amazonaws.com/upload/users.csv?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ6U4CWQNUWMWSQ7Q&Expires=1499336527&Signature=gO57XqNKJ%2FmlkHDVXsL0i6Ul2CE%3D"`

The error i got
`<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>AKIAJ6U4CWQNUWMWSQ7Q</AWSAccessKeyId>`

Should we use same key name when we upload the object.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Finally it got fixed. I generated a signed url using the following  node.js snippet
`

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
aws.config.update({region: 'eu-west-1'});
var s3 = new aws.S3({signatureVersion: 'v4'});
const bucketName = 'a055';
const keyName = 'app_dup.js';
const signedUrlExpireSeconds = 60 * 5;
const url = s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: keyName,
   "ContentType":'application/javascript',
    Expires: signedUrlExpireSeconds
});
console.log(url);
```

`Then after i tried the postman tool for uploading an object. Thanks to @runnerpaul. Key headers to be included are`Content-type && Content-length`, without those you will face errors.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately from my experience that error doesn't tell you very much.

I had a similar issue a couple of weeks ago and resolved it by passing a 'Host' key in the header. See [My AWS v4 Authorization Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44057730/aws-authorization-in-java/44196523#44196523).

I found that if I tred o do the operation in Postman the correct signature got generated so I was able to look at what was passed in the header and include that in my code. You may want to try this. Other than that, all I can suggest is a trial and error approach. Also, AWS has some good documentation explaining how the signature is generated. Perhaps you can look through it and work out whats missing.

Comment: Thanks @runnerpaul .

Comment: But here i have used aws cli tool to generate signed url . Does it make any difference?

Comment: Hmmm, I'm no expert so this is just from my own experience but I think if something is missing an incorrect signature may be generated.

Also, are you running that curl immediately after generating the signature? I think it has a timeout.

Comment: Yea I set the timeout of 4000 sec for signed url. After generating I immediately used it

Comment: Its not working .i am loosing my mind in debugging this.

Comment: I feel your pain. Let me have a think.

Comment: Not working with postman too. I got the following err when tried with postman
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
    </Error>`

Comment: Do you know what the a054 is? Never saw that before.

Comment: it is the bucket name.

Comment: Thanks @runnerpaul for guiding me.